# How to output an array of string circularly every second through Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

let's say there are couple words here : apple, bpple, cpple

I want to show them into a  circularly

second 1:apple
then second 2:bpple
then 3:cpple
then 4:apple
...

like dynamically change the value in a `'<div>value</div>'` every second

how can i achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you actually want here. Show them how? One at a time? How is the next shown? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i understood your problem,try the this code:

```
<div id="demo">
    <h2>{{myArray}}</h2>
    <h3>{{arrayItem}}</h3>
    <br>
    <button @click="startCircular()">start</button>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        myArray:['apple','bpple','cpple'],
        arrayItem: ''
    },
    methods:{
        startCircular(){

            var i = 0;  // the index of the current item to show
            vm = this;
            setInterval(function() {            // setInterval makes it run repeatedly
                vm.arrayItem = vm.myArray[i++];
                if (i == vm.myArray.length) i = 0;   // reset to first element if you've reached the end
            }, 1000);        
        }    
    }
})
```

Look at the demo here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4bgz108/)

Comment: @马露月 happy that i understood your question and was helpful.

Comment: how can i stop it from looping btw

Comment: @马露月 use sopInterval()

Comment: hey, one more question. why can't i use 'this' directly instead of using 'vm=this'?

Comment: @马露月 if you use this directly in setInterval block , it will pount to the setInterval block not the vue instance, so set vm=this outside the setInterval block to point correctly to the vue instance

Comment: @马露月 or if you know aboit how arrow functions ( => ) work you can use arrow function in setInterval like this setInterval(() => { } , 1000). Now no need to use vm=this as arrows functions uses lexical scoping to bind the value of 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) (modulo) to loop through the array cyclically as I have shown in the following example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: { 
    array: ['apple', 'bpple', 'cpple'], 
    counter: 0,
    index: 0,
    value: 'apple', 
    interval: 0 
  },
  methods: {
    start() {
      this.stop();
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.index = ++this.counter % this.array.length;
        this.value = this.array[this.index];
      }, 1000);
    },
    stop() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>counter: {{counter}} / index: {{index}} / value: {{value}}</div>
  <button @click="start()">start</button>
  <button @click="stop()">stop</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i mean, dynamically change the value in a '<div>value</div>' every second, apologize for my incorrect description

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the clarifications you have made.